# incompatible Solidity versions

Tags: solidity, solc, foundry, compiler

I am trying to compile the code with multiple solidity versions e.g. =0.7.6, =0.8.15 etc in foundry with the configuration of auto_detect_solc but still getting this error

Here's my foundry.toml file

```
[profile.default]
  auto_detect_solc = true
  block_timestamp = 1_680_220_800
  bytecode_hash = "none"
  cbor_metadata = false
```

Also, solc_version is not set.

I am getting this error
[image]

Comment: Your deploy script is probably importing contract with a different version than 0.8.15. Can you double check that? If you cannot update the contracts version, you can create an interface with something like ^0.8.0 to be compatible with the "immutable" contract you need to import.

Comment: I have imported Algebra V1 interfaces it is compiled in 0.7.6 and my contracts are on 0.8.15 but I want compiler to compile both different versions isn't possible?

Comment: It is possible, but if you have =0.7.6 and =0.8.15, then there is no common version the compiler can use. Try defining an interface with version ^0.7.6 for Algebra V1, that the rest of your codebase can use. Then import the interface into your 0.8.15 code (the interface will be compiled for each version separately).